# Empty question details for "picture questions"?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In this question [What is the striped thing on Jango's chin?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5679/99), the question title along with the picture is sufficient to understand the question.

Is it acceptable to submit such questions without any text in the question details? I don't see it useful to repeat the title again, and point out that there's a picture below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're expected to provide some background, and not just an image.

> On [INSERT SERIES HERE] on episode [INSERT EPISODE HERE], we see that [SOME EVENT HAPPENS], how/why/when this happened?
>
> Here's an image:
>
> [image: Blockquote]

Or something similar. It doesn't have to be long. 2-3 sentences providing background and context to the image you're posting.